# how to create a new div background color with typed hexcode in the input field on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

create the background color of the **col-md-3** bootstrap div automatically by entering color in input field. with js and jQuery.

please help : thanks in advance

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="#333333">
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

Bootstrap div :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
/* create a div with background color on click */
</div>
```

jquery code here :

```
var input = $('#input').val();
var save = $('#save');
save.on('click',function() {
/* code here.... */
});
```

Comment: what u want? on clicking save button div color change as test field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// on click of the save button
$("#save").on('click',function() {
    // get the hex color from the input
    var color = $("input").val();
    // create a div
    var $div = $("<div class='color'></div>");

    // change its background-color to the hex color
    $div.css("background-color", color);

    // append it to the container
    $(".col-md-3").append($div);

   
    // SAVE TO LOCALSTORAGE CODE
    var savedColors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colors")) || []; // get the already saved array (or create a new one if nothing is saved yet)
    savedColors.push(color); // add this color to it
    localStorage.setItem("colors", JSON.stringify(savedColors)); // put it back into the local storage with this color added to it.
});
```

```css
.color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="#333333">
<button id="save">Save</button>

<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
```

Comment: @TheV what do you mean _save in local storage_? You mean an array of all the colors or just the last added color?

Comment: which typed in the input field (added color)

Comment: @TheV Check the code! I added the code that add the color to the local storage! And I'm appending divs inside the `col-md-3` div by the way!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.col-md-3').css( "background-color", input );
```

Comment: thanks Areca :) but i want to append col-md-3 div with every new hex code typed in the input field

Answer (score 0):

change your this line og **HTML** code from `<button id="save">Save</button>` to `<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>`

**jQuery**:

```
save.on('click',function() {
  var input = $('#input').val();
  $('.col-md-3').css("background-color", input);
});
```

Comment: thanks Rana Ghosh :) but i want to append col-md-3 div with every new hex code typed in the input field

Comment: @TheV Please update your question and explain a bit what you exactly want.

Comment: when user typed the hexcode in the input field, i want to append everytime a bootstrap div of "col-md-3"  with that background-color and i want to save it the local storage , thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. The value of input must be binded to 'change' event.

```js
var input; 
$('#input').on('change', function() {
  input = $(this).val();
});

var save = $('#save');
save.on('click', function() {
  $('div').css('background', input);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="#333333">
<button id="save">Save</button>

<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
```